# Find the value of x from the figure

Tags: geometry

[image]

As figure not drawn to scale, if I consider BC and CF are not in the same line, is my thinking wrong?

Comment: If you consider that BC and CF are not on the same line, then you definitely cannot solve this problem. Think of it this way, what happens if you just move vertex B a little bit far apart(Along the line AB)? It will not affect any of the specified angles and AB will still be parallel to DC, but the angle B will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework time, mm? Oh wait, are you practicing for some standardized test, like SAT or something? Or maybe these questions are too difficult for SAT... :D

When they say it is not to scale, it means that the lengths, the proportions and the angles are not necessarily exact. Collinearity and  incidence are respected for sure.

Comment: ya, you got me. I am preparing for GRE. Thank you anyway :D

Comment: Haha, it's GRE general, right? I know it's annoying. Then my answer above stands. Definitely collinearity and incidence are respected in such tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think in these cases you can assume that lines that appear to be straight are indeed straight.

You'll probably need to use the fact that triangles $FEC$ and $FAB$ are similar (which assumes that FAB is a triangle!), that angles $AED$ and $CEF$ are vertical angles, etc., to solve the problem.